# Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: php, ubuntu, mysqli, warnings

In PHP I'm getting the following warning whenever I try to connect to a database (via `mysql_connect`)

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50162 Library:50524

In my `php -i` output I have the following values listed under mysqli

> Client API library version => 5.5.24
>
> Client API header version => 5.1.62

I've tried updating php5-mysql *and* php but I'm already at the latest version of both of them. How do I go about updating the header version so I stop seeing this warning?

**EDIT**

My MySQL files should all be updated to be the latest version:

```
$ apt-get install mysql.*5.5
. . .
mysql-client-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-server-core-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-server-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-testsuite-5.5 is already the newest version.
mysql-source-5.5 is already the newest version.
```

Removing old versions

```
$ apt-get remove mysql.*5.1
. . .
Package handlersocket-mysql-5.1 is not installed, so not removed
Package mysql-cluster-client-5.1 is not installed, so not removed
Package mysql-cluster-server-5.1 is not installed, so not removed
Package mysql-client-5.1 is not installed, so not removed
Package mysql-client-core-5.1 is not installed, so not removed
Package mysql-server-5.1 is not installed, so not removed
Package mysql-server-core-5.1 is not installed, so not removed
Package mysql-source-5.1 is not installed, so not removed
```

Comment: you'll have to update the mysql stuff as well. mysql-client or whatever.

Comment: @MarcB I should have all of the latest versions of the MySQL suite (see my latest edit)

Comment: "Client API header" version cannot be upgraded because it is hardcoded into the PHP executable. They was the mysql headers (and libraries) installed on the PHP package mantainer's system at the time PHP was compiled. You cannot upgrade them. You have to fail back to MySQL 5.1.X libraries to make that version of PHP working again, or upgrade PHP to a version compiled with MySQL 5.5.X.

Comment: @dAm2K As it turned out the version *was* able to be upgraded by swapping out my current mysqli.so file with a newer one.

Comment: Sure! If you have mysql as external PHP module, you can try to just upgrade the mysql.so library. You should check that the new mysql.so it's 100% binary compatible with the version of PHP you have, or you may have problems very hard to debug (segmentation faults, invalid or corrupted results, and so on). The better way is to upgrade PHP to a version compiled with MySQL 5.5, or use the linux vendor's RPMs.

Comment: This may be a new question altogether, but do you know how I'd go about checking to see if it's completely compatible with my current version of PHP? So far nothing's blown up and the errors have gone away, but I certainly don't want anything screwy happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I really don't know if there is a way to check ABI compatibility... you just have to check apache error_log for strange httpd child errors. If after 3-4 days the error doesn't come, you should be ok.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your PHP was compiled with MySQL 5.1 but now it is linking a mysql library of 5.5.X family.
You have to upgrade PHP to a version compiled with MySQL 5.5 or revert back mysql client libraries to 5.1.x.

Comment: Basically this was the problem I was having, but rather than upgrade or downgrade anything, I was able to pull the mysqli.so file from a server with PHP compiled with MySQL 5.5 and just stick it in my /usr/lib/php5/ directory. I'm not sure it's the safest route to go, however, so I don't want to use that as the go-to answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 132):

I am using MariaDB and have a similar problem.

From [MariaDB site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/), it is recommended to fix it by

1. Switch to using the mysqlnd driver in PHP (Recommended solution).
2. Recompile PHP with the MariaDB client libraries.
3. Use your original MySQL client library with the MariaDB.

My problem was fixed by using the mysqlnd driver in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

---

[update: extra information] Installing this driver also resolve PDO problem that returns integer value as a string. To keep the type as integer, after installing mysqlInd, do this

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $user, $pass, 
          array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
```

Comment: php5-mysqlnd driver works, but answer should note, that apache2ctl restart is required

Answer (score 70):

For new MySQL 5.6 family you need to install php5-mysqlnd, not php5-mysql.

Remove this version of the mysql driver

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-mysql
```

And install this instead

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Comment: Please explain your answer some. Things like what these packages do.

Comment: For new MySQL 5.6 family you need to install php5-mysqlnd, not php5-mysql.

Comment: It solved the issue. I was facing this issue when I upgraded MySql (AWS RDS MySql Instance) from 5.5 to 5.6.

Comment: Obviously restarting Apache is needed for this to work properly. Just pointing the obvious

Comment: This broke my phpMyAdmin. Itseems phpMyAdmin can not work with MySQL native driver.

Comment: ^^^ this did not *simply* work, ... gave error:  `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfontconfig1 : Breaks: xpdf (<= 3.03-11) but 3.03-10 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages`.  Did not know how to revert back (after I removed php-mysql, it would not let me install it back).  In the process of fixing this, had to update apache, fix apache config, and also update PHP to latest available stable versions and fix some other issues, like `perl: warning: Setting locale failed (LANGUAGE, LC_ALL)`

Answer (score 23):

The same works for MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

I've read this thread trying to find the solution for MySQL, and I've also seen ken's answer, but I ignored the solution for MariaDB, wasting a few hours that way. It wasn't clear for me that the same may apply to MySQL. This post is just to spare you the few hours I lost.

Comment: good fix for me, followed by 
    
    sudo systemctl restart mysql
    
    sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: It is much better to do the install and let the dependencies remove php5-mysql. Some systems do not like the purge of php5-mysql without an alternative.

Answer (score 12):

The root reason for this error is that PHP separated itself from the MySQL Client libraries some time ago. So what's happening (mainly on older compiles of linux) is that people will compile PHP against **a given build of the MySQL Client** (meaning the version of MySQL installed is irrelevant) and not upgrade (in CentOS this package is listed as `mysqlclientXX`, where `XX` represents the package number). This also allows the package maintainer to support lower versions of MySQL. It's a messy way to do it, but it was the only way given how PHP and MySQL use different licensing.

[MySQLND](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) solves the problem by using PHP's own native driver (the ND), which no longer relies on MySQL Client. It's also compiled for the version of PHP you're using. This is a better solution all around, if for no other reason that MySQLND is made to have PHP talk to MySQL.

If you can't install MySQLND you can actually safely ignore this error for the most part. It's just more of an FYI notice than anything. It just sounds scary.

Answer (score 7):

My hosting company told me to fix this by deactivating "mysqli" and activating "nd_mysqli" in the php extensions.

The error is gone, but I don't have the knowledge to understand if this is the right method to fix this.

Comment: Shortest solution without making any code changes! Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

To compile php from source with [MySQL native driver (mysqlnd)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/),

```
cd /php/source/path
./configure <other-options> --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql
make clean    # required if there was a previous make, which could cause various errors during make
make
make install
```

From `/php/source/path/configure --help`.

```
--with-mysql=DIR        Include MySQL support.  DIR is the MySQL base
                      directory, if no DIR is passed or the value is
                      mysqlnd the MySQL native driver will be used
--with-mysqli=FILE      Include MySQLi support.  FILE is the path
                      to mysql_config.  If no value or mysqlnd is passed
                      as FILE, the MySQL native driver will be used
--with-pdo-mysql=DIR    PDO: MySQL support. DIR is the MySQL base directory
                      If no value or mysqlnd is passed as DIR, the
                      MySQL native driver will be used
```

One or more PHP MySQL extensions can be included by using these options.
If a value is not passed to these options, or if the value is `mysqlnd`, MySQL native driver will be used.

Comment: Your answer was so valuable to me. In it, I read that I had to use BOTH `--with-mysql` and `--with-mysqli` options to properly use the compiled driver. So I did again my configure command this time with: `  --with-mysql=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install \
  --with-mysqli=/home/stephane/programs/mariadb/install/bin/mysql_config \` and the issue was solved. It now uses the correct MariaDB client version.

Answer (score 1):

I got same php warring in my wordpress site...

> Err: Warning: mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50547 Library:50628 in /home/lhu/public_html/innovacarrentalschennai.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1515

Cause: I updated wp 4.2 to 4.5 version (PHP and MySql mismatch )

I changed wp-db.php on line 1515

```
$this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
```

to

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    $this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
} else {
    $this->dbh = @mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
}
```

Its got without warring err on my wordpress site

Comment: Just an FYI, this will stop working under PHP7 because the [mysql_ functions have been removed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

If u had access cpanel or whm for domain web hosting ...

In cPanel, Go to "Softwares and services" tab, >> and then click "Select PHP Version" >> set your desired version of php...

[image: Warning: mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50547 Library:50628 in chennaitechnologies.com]

Eg.
Current PHP version:

PHP Version [5.2] ( list of 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 available php versions)

**Warning: Changing php modules and php options via PHP Selector for native php version is impossible**

I selected 5.6 php version, after that error cleared on my wordpress blog site...

Answer (score 1):

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch.
Headers:50547 Library:100026
```

I solved the above error by just rebuilding my Apache:

```
cPanel Version  56.0 (build 25)
Apache Version  2.4.18
PHP Version 5.5.30
MySQL Version   10.0.26-MariaDB
```

Answer (score 0):

For WHM and cPanel, some versions need to explicty set mysqli to build.

Using WHM, under CENTOS 6.9 xen pv [dc]  v68.0.27, one needed to rebuild Apache/PHP by looking at all options and select mysqli to build. The default was to build the deprecated mysql. Now the depreciation messages are gone and one is ready for future MySQL upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on centos7. Removing php-mysql and installing php-mysqlnd fixed the problem. Thanks Carlos Buenosvinos Zamora for your suggestion.

Here are my commands on centos7 just in case this can be of help to anybody as most of the answers here are based on Debian/Ubuntu.

To find the installed php-mysql package

```
yum list installed | grep mysql
```

To remove the installed php-mysql package

```
yum remove php55w-mysql.x86_64
```

To install php-mysqlnd

```
yum install php-mysqlnd.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for **MariaDB 10.6.4-MariaDB**, **php56w**, on **centos 7.7**

1. `yum remove php56w-mysqli`
2. `yum install php56w-mysqlnd`

Answer (score -3):

**Changing PHP version from 5.6 to 5.5 Fixed it**.

You have to go to control panel > CGI Script and change PHP version there.

Comment: We are all trying get on to latest version not going back down in versions.