# Advanced Custom Fields makes Wordpress pages blank - Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site using Advanced Custom Fields Plugin.
A few days ago, the hosting went off and after, I had all my pages with custom fields, blank.

Whith wordpress debugging, I am getting this:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Headers and client
>   library minor version mismatch. Headers:50536 Library:50616 in
>   /home/rays/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1372

Not all pages using custom fields are so blank, only those page which had like 49 custom fields on them.

What`s the problem?

Comment: Do you looked at line 1372?

Comment: $this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );

Comment: maybe this answers can help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch)