# mysql warning during php json script

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am new in android developing.I got warning during querying the remote database.I can't access the database from my android app.please help me. here I attach mysql warning.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): Headers and client library minor version
>   mismatch. Headers:50542 Library:50625 in
>   /home/almadllf/public_html/new.php on line 7

```
{"result":["",{"id":"1","bus_name":"vinayaka","time":"06:50:00"},{"id":"2","bus_name":"kannan","time":"07:30:00"},{"id":"3","bus_name":"kuthirumal kalpaka","time":"07:30:00"},{"id":"4","bus_name":"vinayaka","time":"07:40:00"},{"id":"5","bus_name":"shethrapalaka","time":"08:10:00"}................
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers and client library minor version mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch)

Comment: Check that thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch

Comment: this has NOTHING to do with android.