# How to use phpMyAdmin with mysqlnd

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqlnd

When I run my php code with full error reporting I get :

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch.

I found out that I should switch to mysqlnd by uninstalling mysqli as it is discussed here:
[Headers and client library minor version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch)

After migration I see that phpMyAdmin is not working anymore. so I had to uninstall php-mysqlnd package and install php-mysql again.

So my question is: "Does phpMyAdmin able to work with mysqlnd?"

Comment: I am using Debian 8 and have no problem with the php5-mysqlnd package, which also installs the mysqli extension. So maybe your php-mysqlnd package was incorrectly prepared. Where did it come from?

Comment: I am on CentOS 7, and the php-mysqlnd has no problem, the issue is only about phpMyAdmin which it seems only works with mysql and mysqli. I just can't get the login form of phpMyAdmin while using php-mysqlnd, but after I roll back to php-mysql package the login form appears.

Comment: I don't know which files are part of your php-mysqlnd and php-mysql packages. Maybe you should ask CentOS support about this. What I can tell you is that any PHP program (including phpMyAdmin) talks to MySQL via an extension, for example "mysql" or "mysqli". See http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php for more background details. Also, did you get phpMyAdmin from CentOS 7 itself?

Comment: Yes I install it via issuing "yum install phpMyAdmin". My problem still exists. I can't use phpMyAdmin with mysqlnd.

Comment: Did you try asking CentOS support?

Comment: Not yet, I will try now.

Comment: Ok I got a response from CentOS forum which solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking the same question in CentOS forum, I got a solution to this:

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=53726

The trick is to not issue the "yum remove php-mysql" and "yum install php-mysqlnd" in separate commands, but instead one must issue the following:

```
# yum shell
> remove  php-mysql
> install php-mysqlnd
> run
> quit
```

The above prevents the phpMyAdmin to be remove automatically, and the upgrade will happen smoothly without breaking the phpMyAdmin package.