# Headers and client library minor version mismatch in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am new to opencart. I just migrate my all files from localhost to live server and facing with "headers and client library minor version mismatch " this issue.

please find browse domain- "www.ratandeepsarees.com"
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headers and client library minor version mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch)