# vBulletin: Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection, vbulletin

I've transferred a big vBulletin forum, i have copied the database and the files..
I have modified the credentials to access at the database but I receive an error..
How to solve?

```
mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50547 Library:100026
/var/www/vhosts/chorse.net/httpdocs/forum/includes/class_core.php on line 311
```

Line 311:

```
if (function_exists('catch_db_error'))
{
set_error_handler('catch_db_error');
}

// catch_db_error will handle exiting, no infinite loop here
do
{
--->>>  $link = $this->functions[$usepconnect ? 'pconnect' : 'connect']("$servername:$port", $username, $password);
}
while ($link == false AND $this->reporterror);
```

Comment: Hope this will help you to solve issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch

Comment: No, I had already seen that discussion, but I'm on a hosting .. It 's impossible that have been installed wrong or that the versions are not able to communicate with each other