# Wordpress warning: mysqli_real_connect()

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website in Godaddy but when i try to enter i get this issue:

> warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Headers and client library minor
>   version mismatch. Headers:50519 Library:50633 in
>   /home/content/p3pnexwpnas16_data01/62/3653462/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php
>   on line 1538

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Last time this happened to me it was about my hosting updating MySQL while the PHP version was still lower.
You can simply upgrade your PHP version within you panel [(see this)](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/read-this-first-wordpress-45-master-list/?replies=7#post-8274461) or turn off WordPress debug or find the exact code and make it quiet. according to [this link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp45-upgrade-mysql_connect-error/) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch).

Also it was said that you can use `define('WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', true);` in your `wp-config.php` file.