# Submitting HTML form to PHP file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created two files on remote server. One is html form which asks to enter some fields and another is a php file which will get all the data and insert into the database.

For this from html file on click of submit button I am calling php file, but the file is not getting execute I think because when I click on submit it again reloads the same html page.

html :

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MCQ Questions</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" >

<p> Enter the question :</p> <input name="question" type="input"> <br><br>

<p> Enter options :</p>
Enter option 1 : <input name="opt1" type="input"> <br><br>
Enter option 2 : <input name="opt2" type="input"> <br><br>
Enter option 3 : <input name="opt3" type="input"> <br><br>
Enter option 4 : <input name="opt4" type="input"> <br><br>

<p> Enter correct answer :</p>

<input name="ans" type="input"> <br><br>

<input type="submit" value = "Submit" onClick = "uploadQuestion.php">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php file:

```
    <?php

$question=$_POST['question'];
$option1=$_POST['opt1'];
$option2=$_POST['opt2'];
$option3=$_POST['opt3'];
$option4=$_POST['opt4'];
$ans=$_POST['ans'];


$db_server = mysql_connect("address","username","pass"); 
if(!$db_server) { 
   die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error()); 
}else{
   $db_select = mysql_select_db("mlm",$db_server); 
   if (!$db_select) { 
       die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error()); 
   } 
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO questions (question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer) VALUES ('$question','$option1',$option2,$option3,$option4,$ans)";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

?>
```

I also tried this way :

```
<input type="submit" value = "Submit" onClick = "http://address/uploadQuestion.php">
```

But nothing is working. Whats going wrong here? I am a beginner in web development,, can anyone help please? Thank you..

EDIT :

```
  $database = new Database('addredd','username','pass','handbook');

  $dbConnection = $database->getDB();

  $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("insert into questions(question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->execute(array($question,$option1,$option2,$option3,$option4,$ans));
```

I tried to use pdo statement but getting this error :
Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in /var/www/html/uploadQuestion.php on line 12

EDIT2 :

I am trying to upload one file on server and want to save it in database also, so for this I have created 2 files one is index.php and another is uploadFile.php.

As you shown now I used pdo for this but when I click on upload image again same page is getting load.

index.php

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p> Select image to upload:</p>
    <input name = "file" type="file" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>
    Enter chapter name :
    <input name = "chapterName" type = "text"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value = "Upload Image">
    </form>


<?php

if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{

    $ch = curl_init();

    $cfile = new CURLFile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['type'],$_FILES['file']['name']);

    $data = array("myfile" => $cfile);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://host/NewProject/uploadFile.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOTP_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if($response == true)
    {
        echo "File posted";

    }
    else{

        echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }

}

?>
```

uploadFile.php

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']))
{
    $path = "files/" . $_FILES['myfile']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $path);

    $chapterName=$_POST['chapterName']; 

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=database_name','username', 'password');


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO chapters (title,file) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($chapterName,$path));

if ($dbh->lastInsertId())
{
    echo 'File upploaded.';
}
else
{
    echo 'File could not upload.';
}


}
    ?>
```

Please help.. Thank you..

Comment: Remove `onClick = "uploadQuestion.php"` on your button and add `action="uploadQuestion.php"` inside the opening `<form>` tag. The [**PHP manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) also has examples on how to deal with forms, you should start there.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? 
Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)
 - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which.

Comment: `type="input"` isn't a valid type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: and your query is failing you

Comment: you also have no action for `<form>` which suggests you're using the entire code in the same file and you should be getting errors on that also in the php.

Comment: and open to a serious sql injection.

Comment: u don't have Class "Database"

Comment: how can I do this using  pdo? @Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First repair your form, `type=""` can't be named `input` u can check here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MCQ Questions</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="uploadQuestion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p> Enter the question :</p> <input name="question" type="text"> <br><br>

    <p> Enter options :</p>
    Enter option 1 : <input name="opt1" type="text"> <br><br>
    Enter option 2 : <input name="opt2" type="text"> <br><br>
    Enter option 3 : <input name="opt3" type="text"> <br><br>
    Enter option 4 : <input name="opt4" type="text"> <br><br>

    <p> Enter correct answer :</p>

    <input name="ans" type="text"> <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Then yours `php` code

```
<?php

// mysql connection
$db_server = mysql_connect("address","username","pass"); 

// check for mysql connection
if(!$db_server)
{ 
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error()); 
}
else
{
    // check if database exists
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("mlm",$db_server); 

    if (!$db_select)
    { 
        die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error()); 
    } 
}

// escape post variables
$question = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question']);
$option1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['opt1']);
$option2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['opt2']);
$option3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['opt3']);
$option4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['opt4']);
$ans = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ans']);




// make query
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions (question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer) VALUES ('$question', '$option1', '$option2', '$option3', '$option4', '$ans')";

// check if query runs    
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

?>
```

Or `php` with `mysqli`

```
<?php

// host, username, password, database name
$db_server = mysqli_connect("address", "username", "pass", "mlm"); 

// check for connection
if(!$db_server)
{ 
   die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
}

// escape post variables
$question = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $_POST['question']);
$option1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $_POST['opt1']);
$option2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $_POST['opt2']);
$option3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $_POST['opt3']);
$option4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $_POST['opt4']);
$ans = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $_POST['ans']);

// make query
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions (question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer) VALUES ('$question', '$option1', '$option2', '$option3', '$option4', '$ans')";

// check if query runs
if (!mysqli_query($db_server, $sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
}

?>
```

Or `php` with prepared statements

```
<?php

// mysql connection
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=adress;dbname=database_name', 'username', 'password');

// escape post variables
$question = $_POST['question'];
$option1 = $_POST['opt1'];
$option2 = $_POST['opt2'];
$option3 = $_POST['opt3'];
$option4 = $_POST['opt4'];
$ans = $_POST['ans'];


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($question, $option1, $option2, $option3, $option4, $ans));

if ($dbh->lastInsertId())
{
    echo 'Sucess.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Fail.';
}

?>
```

Comment: I am getting this error : mysqli_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50550 Library:50631 in /var/www/html/uploadQuestion.php on line 34

Comment: do u coding on localhost, xampp ?

Comment: its remote server

Comment: it seems that is problem with `mysql` version on your server, u can check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch

Comment: I am also getting same issue in another file can I edit the question will u help me out?

Comment: sure no problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138394/discussion-between-sid-and-mario).

Answer (score -2):

Change your from code to this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MCQ Questions</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="uploadQuestion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p> Enter the question :</p> <input name="question" type="input"> <br><br>

    <p> Enter options :</p>
    Enter option 1 : <input name="opt1" type="input"> <br><br> Enter option 2 : <input name="opt2" type="input"> <br><br> Enter option 3 : <input name="opt3" type="input"> <br><br> Enter option 4 : <input name="opt4" type="input"> <br><br>

    <p> Enter correct answer :</p>

    <input name="ans" type="input"> <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```