# Codeigniter error fetching data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

I made a program in php and it works properly (the php program works properly NOT the codeigniter version). Now, i wanna make that program using Codeigniter.

Here is my php program:

```
    <?php include('connect.php');

?>

<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
    <body>

    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">



    <a href="estudiante.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">AGREGAR</button></a><br /><br />
        <h2 align="center">TABLA:MATERIAS</h2>
        <input id="busqueda_tabla" type="text">
            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Carrera</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Carga horaria (hs)</th>
                    <th>Accion</th>
                </thead>

    <?php

                $sql=mysql_query("SELECT s.*, c.nombre AS carrera FROM materias s LEFT JOIN carreras c ON s.carrera_id=c.id");//ESTA FUNCION ME AYUDA A ACOMODAR LAS CARRERAS EN LA COLUMNA "CARRERA" DE LA TABLA
                $i=1;
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                        echo "<tr>
                                <td>".$i."</td>
                                <td>".$row['carrera']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['descripcion']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['carga_horaria']."</td>
                                <td align='center'>
                                    <a href='editar.php?editar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDITAR</button></a> |
                                    <a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>
                                </td>
                        </tr>";
                        $i++;

                    }
                ?>


            </table>    

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>



</html>
```

And, "connect.php" file

```
    <?php

    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root')OR die('error : '.mysql_error());
    $db=mysql_select_db('desafio');

    if($db){
        echo '';

    }else{
        echo 'Error :' .mysql_error(); 
    }


?>
```

This is my Codeigniter code:

My "view" file:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>


    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <h2 align="center">TABLA:MATERIAS</h2>
        <input id="busqueda_tabla" type="text">
            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Carrera</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Carga horaria (hs)</th>
                    <th>Accion</th>
                </thead>


    <?php
        $i=1;
        foreach($records as $record) {

            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$i."</td>
                      <td>".$record->carrera."</td>
                      <td>".$record->nombre."</td>
                      <td>".$record->descripcion."</td>
                      <td>".$record->carga_horaria."</td>
                      <td align='center'>
                         <a href='editar.php?editar=1&iden=".$record->id."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDITAR</button></a> |
                         <a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$record->id."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>";
        }
        $i++;
    ?>
    </table>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my Crudmodel file:

```
      <?php

    Class Crudmodel extends CI_Model{

        public function getRecords(){

            $this->db->select('s.*, c.nombre AS carrera')
                     ->from('materias s')
                     ->join('carreras c', 's.carrera_id = c.id', 'left');
            $q = $this->db->get();

            if($q -> num_rows() > 0){

                return $q->result();
            }

            return false;

        }

    }


?>
```

And the controller file:

```
    <?php

    class Home extends CI_Controller{

        public function index(){
            $this->load->model('Crudmodel');
            $data['records'] = $this->Crudmodel->getRecords();
            $this->load->view('home', $data['records']);

        }
    }
?>
```

But it does not work, i got this errors:

```
https://i.gyazo.com/607303edcd861d0a2257611c925f3e6e.png
https://i.gyazo.com/eb9d833bf5d0818db2906ec1447550c0.png
https://i.gyazo.com/c5bb77d50315888a375a1e775a5ad68c.png
```

My database and autoload files:

```
https://i.gyazo.com/ef7eb80b6f484e4831b78a3408a05b48.png
https://i.gyazo.com/ecf3de9845ed039f877613ffef4e6aa7.png
```

Dont know what to do :/, can help me to figure it out?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT s.*, c.nombre AS carrera FROM materias s LEFT JOIN carreras c ON s.carrera_id=c.carrera_id");
```

Instead of

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT s.*, c.nombre AS carrera FROM materias s LEFT JOIN carreras c ON s.carrera_id=c.id");
```

Comment: Mate, that line belongs to the "old" code. It is working properly, the problem is the Codeigniter version :S

Answer (score 0):

When you pass data from controller to the view, pass it as an array, not a simple variable.

check your connection in config/database all parameters.

Load your header and footer in controller

```html
   <?php

    class Home extends CI_Controller{

        public function index(){
            $this->load->model('Crudmodel');
            $data['records'] = $this->Crudmodel->getRecords();
            $this->load->view('header'); 
            $this->load->view('home', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }
?>
```