# Connect db it shows error (Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50552 Library:50631)

Tags: php

When running below code it shows error like this

```
$link = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

> **Warning:** mysqli_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50552 Library:50631

I am using php 7.1.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headers and client library minor version mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch)

Comment: how to resolve this issue

Comment: @sridhard Did you try to look at the duplicate link and apply proposed solutions in there?