# Warning PHP Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to connect with a mysql databse and I receive this Warning:

(using mysql_ or mysqli_ the problem with the mistmatch is the same)

Warning: mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50173 Library:50312 in /home/u709086394/public_html/Connections/users.php on line 7

this is the file users.php:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'mysql.hostinger.com.ar';
$database = 'u709086394_db01';
$username = 'u709086394_admin';
$password = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect database");
?>
```

My web Host service is Hostinger, configured as PHP 5.4 and create the Database using phpMyadmin. (I don't know how select or change the MySQL Version)

I am using Dreamweaver as editor on W7

How I can resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headers and client library minor version mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860046?s=1|0.0000#12860046

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Comment: JYoThI If I use mysqli_ I receive the same Warning