# mysql warning mismatch brtween mysql version

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, ssh

I have Ubuntu server I tried to install yum packages by the following command

```
sudo apt-get install yum*
```

after installed the website has become not available and gave me error I'll attached error by screen shot below
[image]

and after that I remove yum* packages to return to last configuration and let website work as expected after remove yum weird issue happened it is mysql warning

```
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50554 Library:50635

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 201
```

so I searched in the Internet and I didn't find the solution 
I used
 **PHP 7.0.20-2~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 14 2017 05:55:23) ( NTS )**
**mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.55, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3** 
**Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)**

And also after that I can't make ssh connect with my server when I trying to connect as ssh I got this error

```
ssh: connect to host myhostdomain.com port 22: Connection refused
```

known every things in the past has been works well

Any help please,,

And thanks in advance,

Comment: did this help or you tried ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch

Comment: I can't make ssh connection to server and I've tried to do that through webmin but that does not work