# Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, linux, opencart

Facing this issues with my website after updating mysql using WHM.

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50542 Library:50635 in /home/narendrapal/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7

I have my own dedicated server running CentOs Linux 7.
please do explain the solution in steps as I am not a professional. 
Thanks!

Comment: You need to update the PHP mysql extension to match the updated mysql.

Comment: how do I do that ?

Comment: yum -y remove mysql56w-mysql && yum -y install php56w-mysqlnd

Answer (score -2):

Your PHP was compiled with different MySQL version and now it is linking a mysql library of different version. You have to upgrade PHP to a version compiled with MySQL or revert back mysql client libraries to lower.

One option is to pull the mysqli.so file from a server with PHP compiled with MySQL and just add it in /usr/lib/php5/ directory. This worked for me.
If this does not, try solutions in similar question here - 
[Headers and client library minor version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch)

Comment: how do I upgrade php to a version compiled with MySQL?